# JavaScript transition between images on top of others by Z-index

Tags: javascript, image, loops, z-index, transition

I have 30 images whose file names are the same, but ending with a number in a range of 1 to 30. Each image has a z-index from the same range, placing them on top of each other in the same div. Now, I want the image on top to go to the bottom, while I increment the other images' z-index by 1, consecutively, until the image with the id="image30" reaches a certain position, for the loop to stop. When I execute this code in Firefox I get a pop-up window requesting me to stop the script, but when I check the console for errors there are none.

```
function placeImage(x) {
    var div = document.getElementById("div_picture_right");
    div.innerHTML = ""; // clear images

    for (counter=1;counter<=x;counter++) {
        var image=document.createElement("img");
        image.src="borboleta/Borboleta"+counter+".png";
        image.width="195";
        image.height="390";
        image.alt="borboleta"+counter;
        image.id="imagem"+counter;
        image.style.position="absolute";
        image.style.zIndex=counter;
        div.appendChild(image);
    }
};

var animaRight = function(x) {
    var imageArray = [];
    for (counter=0;counter<x-1;counter++) {
        imageArray[counter] = document.getElementById("imagem"+counter+1);
        }
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (var number in imageArray) {
            if (imageArray[number].style.zIndex==number+1) {
                imageArray[number].style.zIndex=imageArray.length-counter;
            }
        }
    }, 1000/x);
};

window.onload = function() {
    placeImage(30);
    document.getElementById("div_picture_right").onclick=function() {animaRight(30)}
};
```

---

If you need more code to help analyze my problem, I'll gladly edit this. I'd appreciate examples where I can peek at the code for analysis, more than a solution I can copy paste. Directions are most welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the point of incrementing the other images' z-index by 1?

Comment: It's like sending a card to the back of the deck. What was once the last card, becomes the second-to-last card. In this case, "image29" becomes "image30", while the previous "image30" becomes "image1".

Comment: That's my point, you just need to move one card...

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my self right, but these images will animate something, so I need to get each image to the back of the deck consecutively until what was once the first image shown reaches the same position again. I'm sorry if I'm not making myself clear...

Comment: What you said is that I could simply give the last card a Z-index=0 and it would still move out from the top.

Comment: Exactly :-) Or start with higher z-indexes (1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is checking on ultimateImagem. Maybe instead you mean to check on image? For example:

```
    while (image.style.zIndex != x-1) {
      ...
    }
```

Your while loop doesn't modify ultimaImagem, so checking on `ultimaImagem.style.zIndex` creates an infinite loop.

Also, as I said in the comments, you could just move the top image, no need to re-index the others. For example give imagem1 a z-index of 1001, imagem2 a z-index of 1002, etc. Then your code just becomes:

```
var ultimaImagem = document.getElementById("imagem"+x);
ultimateImagem.style.zIndex -= x;
```

Comment: no, ultimaImagem is the image with an id of "imagem"+x. The position doesn't make any difference.

Comment: So, does that mean that the "x" is not being replaced by 30?

Comment: x is replaced by 30, but it doesn't change the fact that it becomes an infinite loop, as ultimaImagem.style.zIndex != 29 will always be true